# Can I connect 2 monitors to my 2015 Macbook Pro Retina via 2x DisplayPort connections?

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, displayport

I have 2x 24" HD monitors. Each has VGA, DVI and HDMI ports. I want to use both of them without mirroring. I do not want to use my MacBook's own screen (it will be closed) when I connect the others.

I have managed to connect the screens by using one DisplayPort->HDMI cable and one HDMI->HDMI cable. That works fine, except, because the HDMI port is on the other side of the laptop to all of the other points I need, it makes the desk a bit messy.

So I bought a second DisplayPort->HDMI cable. When I connect the second one, the system freezes up and the second monitor stays blank.

My research suggests that the MacBook Pro 2015's GPU is meant to support one DisplayPort monitor plus its own screen - but can I configure it to use two DisplayPort monitors and not use its own screen?

(There are lots of similar questions but I couldn't find one that specifically deals with 2x DisplayPort cables)

Comment: Need specs to answer question. You may find them by clicking the  -> About this Mac. As those with actual graphics cards are able to support different display capabilities.

Comment: It has Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB (integrated graphics).

Answer (score 3):

I found conflicting information about this subject, so for the sake of clarity for anyone asking the same question:

- As per the comment [@James](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/222842/james) left on [@Bret's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/110485/bret7600) answer, the Mid 2015 MacBook Pro with Intel Iris graphics CANNOT drive two DisplayPort monitors simultaneously, so it is not possible to run two external 4K displays at 60Hz. This was tested on the 15" model with standard Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cables.
- You can however run one 4K display at 60Hz through a DisplayPort and a second 4K display through the HDMI port at 30Hz.

Answer (score 1):

With the 15" MacBook Pro with Iris Pro integrated graphics, you may use 2 External Displays along with the current Mac Display

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels on up to two external displays
>
> Source: [Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP719?locale=en_US)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work. I can connect two via HDMI+DisplayPort but not DisplayPort+DisplayPort.